# Apex (Salesforce) - How to silence "File ignored because of a matching ignore pattern"

Tags: eslint

I am trying to remove all errors related to `eslint` and I successfully did it by adding `/force-app/main/default/` into my `.eslintignore` file.
But the problem is, now I get this warning:

`File ignored because of a matching ignore pattern. Use "--no-ignore" to override.`

I tried to find the solution and I come across to this question in stackoverflow:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37927772/how-to-silence-warnings-about-ignored-files-in-eslint

But solutions stated in that question unfortunately don't work for me.
I mean to this one solution
*Another way not to show that warning is to use dir names: eslint src instead of globbing patterns: eslint src/*.*

Does anyone know is there any way to ignore/exclude that warning?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, I hope it will help someone. It is only important to run the command with the `--engine 'pmd'`.
For example:
`sfdx scanner:run --target "**/default/**" --pmdconfig "config/config.xml" --engine 'pmd'`